# Silent failure loading page application in iframe over https

Tags: facebook, iframe, https, facebook-page

**Problem**

I have an application driving a tab on a client's page. The application works correctly if the user has not enabled FB's "secure browsing" feature. If attempting to view over HTTPS, the iframe doesn't even appear (no errors, no mixed-content warnings). When correctly loading over HTTP, the div with the id "pagelet_app_runner" has an iframe inserted into it and the application content is loaded inside there. Over HTTPS, this div remains empty and the iframe is not inserted into the page. There are no Javascript errors appearing in Firebug or Chrome's equivalent console.

**Why I'm Asking Here**

The host has a valid SSL certificate and there is no 'mixed content' at the URL in question. I can successfully view the content over HTTP or HTTPS by visiting the URL directly, and I can do the same by visiting apps.facebook.com/canvasURL/tabURL. It is only when attempting to view within a Page Tab that the HTTPS load fails as described above. My application is configured with both regular and secure canvas and tab URLs.

**Attempted Debugging**

I've recorded some sessions with Charles but since the iframe isn't being inserted into the page, I think I'm coming at the problem after it's already occured. I'm no Charles expert so happy to be corrected here.

Apache isn't seeing any request (in either regular or ssl logs) for the affected loads. non-SSL loads come through as expected in `access_log`.

**Plea for Help**

I'm out of ideas for debugging this. Does anybody have any suggestions? What really obvious and stupid mistake might I have made? :)

edit: nicer formatting

Comment: Could you provide the URL of the page so we can test the application and see what's happening?

Comment: Good point - https://www.facebook.com/TheSkinnyCow?sk=app_122381834451561 is the Page/Tab and it should be loading content from https://skinnycomp.nextstudio.com.au/skinnycowcomps/tab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using relative URLs for the regular and secure tab URL fields. From memory relative URLs here were mandatory at some point in the past. It appears now that a relative URL will still work for HTTP but not for HTTPs. Fix: absolute URLs. Hopefully FB update their field validation to match what's required too.

Comment: Hmm...this is exactly the kind of thing I had in mind in my answer, which is why I specifically suggested not only double-checking the Secure Page Tab URL entry, but also setting it to a known good url like `https://encrypted.google.com/`. You said it didn't make any difference...now you are saying that was the problem all along?!

Comment: I was operating under the assumption that relative URLs were OK (there are several good reasons to assume this). I did indeed test different Secure Page Tab URLs, but I did it by altering the Canvas URL and Secure Canvas URL and leaving the Page Tab URL relative. The change was reflected correctly only for the HTTP version so the "known good" change didn't appear to solve anything.

Answer (score 0):

Your app canvas URL is `https://skinnycomp.nextstudio.com.au/skinnycowcomps/` , which send 404 error to Facebook proxy (request is going through proxy when viewing app via tab), also when viewing your app via apps (`https://apps.facebook.com/122381834451561/`), again 404... maybe Facebook proxy is ignoring 404 and posting blank...
Try changing canvas URL to `https://skinnycomp.nextstudio.com.au/skinnycowcomps/tab`, also you can check if your app is accessed via page tab, in `signed_request` there should be `page_id`...

```
23:51:15.379[549ms][total 1667ms] Status: 404[Not Found]
GET https://skinnycomp.nextstudio.com.au/skinnycowcomps/
```

Comment: The Canvas URL returning 404 is intended behaviour, the Tab is the application's only integration point. I have just tried making the Canvas URL return 200 OK with some content; it doesn't appear to have any bearing on the Tab URL (which has never returned 404). Thanks for the suggestion though, I am happy to try anything.

Answer (score 0):

This is a real longshot since I'm sure you've triple checked all the settings, but the blank page can happen if an invalid url is specified in the Page Tab URL field in the app settings. Since it only happens on https, it would imply something specifically with the Secure Page Tab URL entry. It might be worth checking that again, and maybe even re-saving it or changing it to something else to see if it helps.

Comment: No need to defend obvious suggestions, we've all looked for the remote when it's in our hand :) The secure and regular page tab URLs are both the same (the suffix 'tab' on the http/https canvas URLs) so it would be very difficult to make a mistake there. I've tried the old copy-paste-the-text-even-though-it-appears-the-same kind of stuff anyway, but fruitless. In any case I'd also expect to see something in the Apache logs if I had the URL wrong. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Just as a curious experiment, what happens if you set the Secure Page Tab URL to `https://encrypted.google.com/` ? Just to see what happens with a "known entity".

Comment: Fails in the same way regardless of the URL I give it. Also tested with an entirely new setup - new app, different host etc, same result. This really suggests it's something that I'm doing wrong, but I can't for the life of me figure it out :(