# Facebook not appearing in iframe

Tags: javascript, html, dom, iframe

As it can be seen [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gM6aL/1/)  facebook does not appear in `iframe`. My question is facebook blocking it some way, if so how can I do this. I obviously don't want complete solution but little help would be great.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7707712/silent-failure-loading-page-application-in-iframe-over-https

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see this:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options

Facebook denies people from viewing it in an iframe.

> Refused to display 'https://www.facebook.com/' in a frame because it
>   set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'.

Answer (score 1):

> Refused to display 'https://www.facebook.com/' in a frame because it
>   set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'.

Basically search for X-Frame and CORS

Answer (score 1):

Facebook forbids being loaded into an iframe. If you check your debug console you will see the following:

> Refused to display 'https://www.facebook.com/' in a frame because it
>   set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'.